# Error: Sending message through endpoint : null resolving to address

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

**Scenario:**
The API basically calls an endpoint to get the token and then sets the token in the header and calls another endpoint along with other query parameters.

**Problem:**
I'm getting the null resolving to address issue.

```
[2022-11-09 18:08:19,327]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:MsaasproEsb} To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:e763462f-c7dc-4f3d-a8ba-b23c5f66a241, correlation_id: 7dba4bab-4218-48ca-9871-e4c2d249a91b, Direction: request, Payload: {"Data": {"status": 200, "id": 190, "user_id": "secpapi", "email": "Faisal.furqan@secp.gov.pk", "token": "9704e4de2acde3af0686c22d409f831db3d1fd76"}}
[2022-11-09 18:08:19,328]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} - Sending message through endpoint : null resolving to address = https://msaaspro.com/api/v1/scan/pep-scan/?fullname={uri.var.name}&searchtype=fuzzy&fathername={uri.var.fatherName}&dobyear={uri.var.dobYear}&cnic={uri.var.cnic}&mobile={uri.var.mobile}&country={uri.var.country}&name_similarity=90
[2022-11-09 18:08:19,328]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} - SOAPAction: 
[2022-11-09 18:08:19,328]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} - WSA-Action: 
[2022-11-09 18:09:17,775]  INFO {SourceHandler} - Writer null when calling informWriterError
[2022-11-09 18:09:17,775]  WARN {SourceHandler} - STATE_DESCRIPTION = Socket Timeout occurred after accepting the request headers and the request body, INTERNAL_STATE = REQUEST_DONE, DIRECTION = REQUEST, CAUSE_OF_ERROR = Connection between the client and the EI timeouts, HTTP_URL = /msaaspro/send, HTTP_METHOD = POST, SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 180000, CLIENT_ADDRESS = /127.0.0.1:55470, CONNECTION http-incoming-4 Correlation ID : 965986e6-2d6b-4108-aefe-3a7a648eb61a
[2022-11-09 18:10:44,079]  INFO {SourceHandler} - Writer null when calling informWriterError
[2022-11-09 18:10:44,079]  WARN {SourceHandler} - STATE_DESCRIPTION = Socket Timeout occurred after accepting the request headers and the request body, INTERNAL_STATE = REQUEST_DONE, DIRECTION = REQUEST, CAUSE_OF_ERROR = Connection between the client and the EI timeouts, HTTP_URL = /msaaspro/send, HTTP_METHOD = POST, SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 180000, CLIENT_ADDRESS = /127.0.0.1:58755, CONNECTION http-incoming-5 Correlation ID : 1fc72034-a9d1-46ad-9198-d18810065c10
[2022-11-09 18:11:19,011]  INFO {SourceHandler} - Writer null when calling informWriterError
[2022-11-09 18:11:19,011]  WARN {SourceHandler} - STATE_DESCRIPTION = Socket Timeout occurred after accepting the request headers and the request body, INTERNAL_STATE = REQUEST_DONE, DIRECTION = REQUEST, CAUSE_OF_ERROR = Connection between the client and the EI timeouts, HTTP_URL = /msaaspro/send, HTTP_METHOD = POST, SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 180000, CLIENT_ADDRESS = /127.0.0.1:58781, CONNECTION http-incoming-6 Correlation ID : 7dba4bab-4218-48ca-9871-e4c2d249a91b
```

**Source code**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/msaaspro" name="MsaasproEsb" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/send">
        <inSequence>
            <property description="username" name="username" scope="default" type="STRING" value="json-eval($.username)"/>
            <property description="password" name="password" scope="default" type="STRING" value="json-eval($.password)"/>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="post" statistics="enable" uri-template="https://msaaspro.com/api/v1/auth/auth-token/">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <property description="token" name="token" scope="default" type="STRING" value="json-eval($.Data.token)"/>
            <property description="Authorization" name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="fn:concat('Token ', get-property('token'))"/>
            <property description="name" name="uri.var.name" scope="default" type="STRING" value="json-eval($.name)"/>
            <property description="fatherName" name="uri.var.fatherName" scope="default" type="STRING" value="json-eval($.fatherName)"/>
            <property description="dobYear" name="uri.var.dobYear" scope="default" type="STRING" value="json-eval($.dobYear)"/>
            <property description="uniqueKey" name="uri.var.cnic" scope="default" type="STRING" value="json-eval($.cnic)"/>
            <property description="country" name="uri.var.country" scope="default" type="STRING" value="json-eval($.country)"/>
            <property description="mobile" name="uri.var.mobile" scope="default" type="STRING" value="json-eval($.mobile)"/>
            <log level="full"/>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="get" statistics="enable" trace="enable" uri-template="https://msaaspro.com/api/v1/scan/pep-scan/?fullname={uri.var.name}&amp;searchtype=fuzzy&amp;fathername={uri.var.fatherName}&amp;dobyear={uri.var.dobYear}&amp;cnic={uri.var.cnic}&amp;mobile={uri.var.mobile}&amp;country={uri.var.country}&amp;name_similarity=90">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <respond/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

**Question:**
My exact question is why I'm getting null resolving issue while I've set properties for all the parameters that I've passed to the endpoint. I'm able to call the first endpoint and I successfully get the token but somehow I'm unable to call the second endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the property mediators, when you use XPath or JSONPath expressions, you need to use the `expression` parameter instead of `value`. For example,

```xml
<property description="token" name="token" scope="default" type="STRING" value="json-eval($.Data.token)"/>
```

should be updated as follows,

```xml
<property description="token" name="token" scope="default" type="STRING" expression="json-eval($.Data.token)"/>
```

Can you update all the property mediators as above and try them out?

2. I couldn't find a `<respond/>` mediator after the call mediator in your insequence. To send the response back to the client you need to have Respond Mediator.

Regarding the log message `Sending message through endpoint : null resolving to address`, since we have used an anonymous endpoint, the trace logger couldn't resolve a name for the endpoint. That's why it's printing a `null` in the trace log.

Comment: @sanol yes I did the same and it resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are seeing null in the Trace logs. But I assume that's the expected behavior with an HTTP Endpoint. I see a typo in your second URL. Check the following. After `pep-scan` you shouldn't have a `/` before the query params.

```
uri-template="https://msaaspro.com/api/v1/scan/pep-scan?fullname={uri.var.name}&amp;searchtype=fuzzy&amp;fathername={uri.var.fatherName}&amp;dobyear={uri.var.dobYear}&amp;cnic={uri.var.cnic}&amp;mobile={uri.var.mobile}&amp;country={uri.var.country}&amp;name_similarity=90"
```

If that doesn't resolve the issue, try adding the following property before the second HTTP call.

```
<property action="remove" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
```

Add the above in the following order.

```
<property action="remove" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
<property description="token" name="token" scope="default" type="STRING" value="json-eval($.Data.token)"/>
<property description="Authorization" name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="fn:concat('Token ', get-property('token'))"/>
<property description="name" name="uri.var.name" scope="default" type="STRING" value="json-eval($.name)"/>
<property description="fatherName" name="uri.var.fatherName" scope="default" type="STRING" value="json-eval($.fatherName)"/>
<property description="dobYear" name="uri.var.dobYear" scope="default" type="STRING" value="json-eval($.dobYear)"/>
<property description="uniqueKey" name="uri.var.cnic" scope="default" type="STRING" value="json-eval($.cnic)"/>
<property description="country" name="uri.var.country" scope="default" type="STRING" value="json-eval($.country)"/>
<property description="mobile" name="uri.var.mobile" scope="default" type="STRING" value="json-eval($.mobile)"/>
<log level="full"/>
<call>
    <endpoint>
        <http method="get" statistics="enable" trace="enable" uri-template="https://msaaspro.com/api/v1/scan/pep-scan/?fullname={uri.var.name}&amp;searchtype=fuzzy&amp;fathername={uri.var.fatherName}&amp;dobyear={uri.var.dobYear}&amp;cnic={uri.var.cnic}&amp;mobile={uri.var.mobile}&amp;country={uri.var.country}&amp;name_similarity=90">
            <suspendOnFailure>
                <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
            </suspendOnFailure>
            <markForSuspension>
                <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
            </markForSuspension>
        </http>
    </endpoint>
</call>
```

If you still see the issue, enable [wire logs](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/develop/using-wire-logs/) and compare the outgoing message with a direct request and try to find what's different.

Comment: I tried the above suggestions, but nothings seems to work. I'm unable to see anything in wirelogs

Comment: `[2022-11-09 22:34:29,032]  INFO {LogMediator} - main sequence executed for call to non-existent = /api/v1/scan/sanction-scan/?fullname=json-eval%28%24.name%29&fathername=json-eval%28%24.fatherName%29&dobyear=json-eval%28%24.dobYear%29&uniquekey=json-eval%28%24.uniqueKey%29&entity=*&searchtype=fuzzy&country=json-eval%28%24.country%29`

Comment: why its giving **main sequence executed for call to non-existent** issue

Comment: @AyubJamal again you have a additional / in your URL

Comment: yes I have rectified that, its somehow coming in logs but in source "/" has been removed it